Critical Vulnerability detection in pandas Library by Fortify due to read_pickle function
Our company utilizes the pandas library extensively in our software. However, Fortify, our security analysis tool,** flags pandas as having a critical vulnerability due to the read_pickle function**, which has the potential to execute malicious code. Note that we do not use the read_pickle function in our codebase, but Fortify still identifies this as a critical issue.
We have tried to solve this by importing only specific submodules of pandas that we use (to avoid importing the entire library) but Fortify continues to detect the critical vulnerability associated with read_pickle.
from pandas import DataFrame, Series, read_csv

However, Fortify continues to flag the vulnerability.
We wonder if there is a solution to this issue. Is there a way to structure our imports or configure pandas to avoid including read_pickle entirely?
Alternatively, is it possible to address this concern directly within the pandas library to enhance its security profile?


Is there a way to structure our imports or configure pandas to avoid
including read_pickle entirely?

This has been a long standing request from developers in corporate environments where SAST and SCA tools are mandatory. They face blockers from these overzealous security scanning tools that ban pandas from internal enterprise repositories based on disputed CVEs like CVE-2020-13091 (notice how the only actual "exploit" link in that CVE has been dead for years).
Here is an example of a similar request:
Disable read_pickle() function to avoid having security vulnerabilities
Pandas maintainers have refused to make such a change because they consider pickle vulnerabilities to be an upstream cpython issue.
You could still do it on your own though, like this fork does, or you can apply exclusions with Fortify:
https://github.com/yilun11/fanniemae-pandas
